# Combining Adjacent Lines into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, html5-canvas

I have an array containing some Javascript objects.  Each object is actually a horizontal line segment that was pulled from a canvas element.  Each object has the properties "lowx" (the left x-coordinate of the segment), "highx" (the right x-coordiante of the segment), and "yvalue" (the y-coordinate that the line segment occupies, since it's horizontal).

I need a loop that combines all adjacent line segments into the same array.  Here's an *example* array transformation:

Here's an example of what rowarray would look like prior to running through this loop:

```
var rowarray = [
[{"lowx": 210, "highx": 212, "yvalue": 132}],
[{"lowx": 208, "highx": 214, "yvalue": 133}],
[{"lowx": 207, "highx": 215, "yvalue": 134}],
[{"lowx": 207, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 135}],
[{"lowx": 206, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 136}],
[{"lowx": 206, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 138}],
[{"lowx": 205, "highx": 220, "yvalue": 139}],
[{"lowx": 199, "highx": 209, "yvalue": 140}]
]
```

After running through the loop, rowarray should contain two arrays (since there are two groups of adjacent line segments).  The line segments with yvalues of 132-136 would be in the first array and the line segments with yvalues of 138-140 should be in the second array.

So, rowarray would then look like:

```
var rowarray = [
[{"lowx": 210, "highx": 212, "yvalue": 132},
{"lowx": 208, "highx": 214, "yvalue": 133},
{"lowx": 207, "highx": 215, "yvalue": 134},
{"lowx": 207, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 135},
{"lowx": 206, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 136}],

[{"lowx": 206, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 138},
{"lowx": 205, "highx": 220, "yvalue": 139},
{"lowx": 199, "highx": 209, "yvalue": 140}]

]
```

Here's the code that I have, which I think is close to working, but isn't quite there yet.  Usually it rowarray ends up being something completely illogical.  There are null objects (not sure why?) and line segments that should've been placed in the same array are not.

*Due to the nature of the project that this is for, this needs to be done in client-side javascript.  However, use of JQuery is fine and welcomed.*

```
    var keepgoing = 1;
    var errorcounter = 0;
    while (keepgoing == 1) {
        try {
            hadtocombine = 0;
            for (var x = rowarray.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
                for (var w = rowarray.length-1; w >= 0; w--) {
                    for (var q = rowarray[x].length-1; q >= 0; q--) {
                            for (var z = rowarray[w].length-1; z >= 0; z--) {
                                if ((rowarray[x][q].yvalue == (rowarray[w][z].yvalue + 1)) || (rowarray[x][q].yvalue == (rowarray[w][z].yvalue - 1))) {
                                    if ((rowarray[x][q].highx >= rowarray[w][z].lowx) && (rowarray[x][q].highx <= rowarray[w][z].highx)) {
                                        rowarray.splice(w,1);
                                        rowarray.splice(x,1);
                                        rowarray.push(rowarray[x].concat(rowarray[w]));
                                        hadtocombine = 1;
                                    }
                                    else if ((rowarray[x][q].lowx >= rowarray[w][z].lowx) && (rowarray[x][q].lowx <= rowarray[w][z].highx)) {
                                        rowarray.splice(w,1);
                                        rowarray.splice(x,1);
                                        rowarray.push(rowarray[x].concat(rowarray[w]));
                                        hadtocombine = 1;
                                    }
                                    else if ((rowarray[x][q].highx >= rowarray[w][z].highx) && (rowarray[x][q].lowx <= rowarray[w][z].lowx)) {
                                        rowarray.splice(w,1);
                                        rowarray.splice(x,1);
                                        rowarray.push(rowarray[x].concat(rowarray[w]));
                                        hadtocombine = 1;
                                    }
                                    else if ((rowarray[x][q].lowx >= rowarray[w][z].lowx) && (rowarray[x][q].highx <= rowarray[x][q].highx)) {
                                        rowarray.splice(w,1);
                                        rowarray.splice(x,1);
                                        rowarray.push(rowarray[x].concat(rowarray[w]));
                                        hadtocombine = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hadtocombine == 0) { 
                keepgoing = 0;
            }
        } catch (err) { errorcounter++; if(errorcounter >= 20000) { keepgoing = 10; } }
    }
```

Hope I was able to explain this well -- if not comment and I'll revise.  This is my first post (after years of lurking), so I hope I've done this properly.

Thanks!

Comment: this isn't clear at all; what's happening at the moment? what's the problem?

Comment: please speficy the input json and output json needed

Comment: @user93 Please look at the two last code snippets.  That's the content of the variable prior to the loop and then what the content should look like after the loop.  There's no JSON really getting changed; it's just arrays getting reorganized

Comment: then remove other part of the question apart from the array transformation and code snippet since it is not relevant

Comment: @RachelGallen At the moment, adjacent line segments are not getting combined into the same array.  There are segments that should be in the same array but are not after the loop.

Comment: @user93 What is there besides the code snippet and array transformation?  The top section is just explaining the background?

Comment: yes since it is simple array transformation you can abstract out those information from the question.

Comment: I've trimmed the question down and reformatted it -- hopefully it's easier to read/understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following code two segments are adjacent if they intersect on the x axis and they are on neighboring or same y value.

The solution is as follows;

```js
function getAdjacents([x,...xs], r = []){ // x is the first item and xs is the rest of the input array.

  function isAdjacent(a,b){
    return (a.lowx < b.highx && b.lowx < a.highx) && Math.abs(a.yvalue - b.yvalue) < 2;
  }
  
  function groupBy(as, [b,...bs], r = [[],[]]){
    as.some(a => isAdjacent(a,b[0])) ? r[0].push(b[0]) : r[1].push(b);
    return bs.length ? groupBy(as.concat(r[0]), bs, r)
                     : r;
  }
  
  var [as,bs] = xs.length ? groupBy(x,xs) : [[],[]],              // group the rest according to the first element
      cs      = x.concat(as);                                     // first element and it's adjacent elements
  
  return bs.length ? as.length ? getAdjacents([cs].concat(bs),r)  // if adjacent elements are found then keep checking
                               : (r.push(cs), getAdjacents(bs,r)) // if not push previous adjacents into result and start with the remaining
                   : (r.push(cs), r);                             // if no more remaining return result
}

var rowarray = [[{"lowx": 210, "highx": 212, "yvalue": 132}],
                [{"lowx": 208, "highx": 214, "yvalue": 133}],
                [{"lowx": 207, "highx": 215, "yvalue": 134}],
                [{"lowx": 207, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 135}],
                [{"lowx": 206, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 136}],
                [{"lowx": 206, "highx": 216, "yvalue": 138}],
                [{"lowx": 205, "highx": 220, "yvalue": 139}],
                [{"lowx": 199, "highx": 209, "yvalue": 140}]
               ];
               
console.log(getAdjacents(rowarray));
```

So i had to modify my code since it was not returning always the same answer when the input array is shuffled. Now it is fine.

I am using a very unusual pattern for my recursive iterations here. Expressing an array in the `(x:xs)` form is pretty basic knowledge if you know Haskell. ES6 allows similar pattern matching in JS too. I'ts interesting up until i use this i haven't seen it anywhere in no books or blogs.

So it's very simple. If you would like to sum all array items you may do like

```
function sum([x,...xs]){
  return xs.length ? x + sum(xs) : x;
}
```

The [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) would assign the first array item (head) to the `x` variable and the rest (tail) of the array will be assigned to the `...xs` [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) as the `xs` array variable. In another words if i feed the `sum` function with `[1,2,3,4]`, in the first turn `x` is `1` and `xs` is `[2,3,4]`. So you should be able to follow the rest of the recursion.

Now in this answer i am using this pattern very often. However since now you know what it is you can simply follow the logic.

The main function is `getAdjacents` and it has two utility helper functions

1. `isAdjacent`: It takes two segment objects and checks if they are adjacent or not. Returns boolean.
2. `groupBy`: This one takes an array of line segments which are already adjacent as the first argument (which is `as`) and an array of unchecked array of arrays each with a single segment object (the tail of `rowarray` initially) as `[b,...bs]`. And it will return a tuple of adjacent and not adjacent like `[[{adj. segment}{adj. segment}...{adj. segment}],[[{segment}],[{segment}],...,[{segment}]]]`.

Any you should be able to carry on with the body of the main function which is commented.

Comment: This is just what I needed!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey -- if it's not too much trouble, would you be able to add a few comments specifying what each line is doing and the logic behind it?

Comment: @DanD Sorry just could find some time to work it. I have modified it a little. Now it seems much solid. I have also added explanation in my answer and comments to the code. Feel free to ask if there is something you get stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve the result by using a simple filter and map method

```js
var rowarray = [
  [{
    "lowx": 210,
    "highx": 212,
    "yvalue": 132
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 208,
    "highx": 214,
    "yvalue": 133
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 207,
    "highx": 215,
    "yvalue": 134
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 207,
    "highx": 216,
    "yvalue": 135
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 206,
    "highx": 216,
    "yvalue": 136
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 206,
    "highx": 216,
    "yvalue": 138
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 205,
    "highx": 220,
    "yvalue": 139
  }],
  [{
    "lowx": 199,
    "highx": 209,
    "yvalue": 140
  }]
]

const group = [{
    l: 132,
    h: 136
  },
  {
    l: 138,
    h: 140
  }
];

rowarray = rowarray.map(x => x[0])

const limit = (h, l, x) => x.yvalue <= h || x.yvalue <= l
let gg = [];
group.map(g => {
  gg.push(rowarray.filter(x => limit(g.l, g.h, x)))
});


console.log(gg)
```

Comment: This works for the example array that I wrote, but that was just an example.  For my specific scenario, the contents of rowarray are user-generated, so the loop would need to be able to work with an arbitrary amount of groups (and can't filter based on specific x and y values, since the x and y values can be anything).  I'm completely self-taught and learn as I go along, so if you could also provide some comments as to how it's working, that'd be useful.

Comment: You can replace the valued 132,146,138,140 dynamically as needed.

Comment: If you have the group as array of objects then you can map through it and apply the above code

Comment: now it will work with any arbitrary group from the group array.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the whole point is for the algo the figure out what the groups are.  I have no problem transforming an array -- that's easy.  But the algo needs to figure out how the array should be transformed based on whether or not the lines are adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified clearly - what segments are "adjacent", but seems you need something like [connected-component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) (with segments instead of cells) and need to implement a kind of [union-find algorithm](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf), making [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

This problem could be also considered as rectangle union problem from computational geometry (solved by union-find and/or sweep line approach)